# Converter mm:ss em milissegundos

Tags: jquery, data

Gostaria de converter o valor mm:ss em milisegundos, poderiam me orientar de como fazer isso?

```
var time = '03:51';
var mili = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 minutos tem:

```
180 segundos
```

Cada segundo tem 1000 milissegundos:

```
180*1000 = 180.000 milissegundos
```

51 segundos tem:

```
51*1000 = 51.000 milissegundos
```

Somando tudo:

```
180.000 + 51.000 = 231.000 milissegundos
```

**Código:**

```js
var time = '03:51';
var time_array = time.split(":").map(Number); // separo mm e ss em array tipo Number

// faço as contas: converter os minutos em segs (*60)
// e depois em mili (*1000).
// E os segundos também (*1000). Depois é só somar.
var mili = (time_array[0]*60*1000) + (time_array[1]*1000);
console.log(mili);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!